# Discord Privacy: If my status is set as Invisible, will a discord server know that I have logged in to my account?

Tags: privacy, discord

While using discord on a Browser & having set my status as Invisible. I am a subscriber to a Discord Server.

If I open Discord on the browser, then will the Discord Server admin of a Server I am subscribed to know that I have logged into Discord if I don't comment in a channel on his server?

I may have done any of the other following stuff after opening discord on the browser (which would have automatically logged me into discord because of my cookies)

- I may have done nothing at all after opening discord on the browser
- I may have PM'ed some friend on discord
- I may have gone to some channel on that discord server I have subscribed to but haven't commented on any channel on that server. I may be scrolled up & down on the channel using a mouse.

In any of these cases is there a way for the server Admin to know that I have logged into Discord?

I know there are several discord logging bots which a server admin can invite to his server. Does the answer to my question change assuming presence of any of these bots on the server? Or if the server admin has access to Discord APIs?

Comment: @user93353 If [LPChip's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146305) solved your problem consider accepting it so others know that.

Answer (score 3):

No. To a Discord Channel admin, you will appear as offline. I manage a discord server, and one of the users in there I know is online, but set to invisible, and to me, this user appears as offline.

The only thing that may give you away is if you start typing something in any of the channels (regardless of actually pressing enter to send it).  When you start typing a "typing indicator" is displayed next to your name even in the offline section. An admin must see that though, as it isn't logged by default.

Keep in mind, that friending a server admin may show this typing indicator in their friends list too.

A logging bot can see the same as the user or admin privileges you allow it, and could be set to log this information, but you have to question the usefulness of logging events of this type.

I personally would not log "user x started to type" in my log as it would fill the log with useless information, waste space, and make looking back through the log for issues that much harder. I would, however, log 'join', 'leave', and certain other actions.